# ¿Cómo crear un fichero .txt en java?

Tags: java

Tengo dudas con la creación de ficheros. El siguiente programa crea un fichero .txt en mi escritorio, con el texto "Texto prueba".

Mi duda es: Supongamos que lo exporto como un .jar, ¿cómo hago para ejecutarlo en otra computadora sin que me marque el error por la ruta?

```
public class Escribir_Fichero {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Escribiendo x = new Escribiendo();
    x.escribir();

    }
}

class Escribiendo {

public void escribir() {

    String frase = "Texto prueba";

    try {
        FileWriter escritura = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Schrödinger/Desktop/ficheroNuevo.txt");

        for(int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {

            escritura.write(frase.charAt(i));

        }

        escritura.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Hmm, cada computadora tiene sus archivos, tienes que ajustar el path al S.O.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663023/java-file-path-windows-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663023/java-file-path-windows-linux) Te recomiendo que veas este ejemplo.

Comment: Utiliza la solución de @Roberto E Morán que es la que mejor se aproxima a tu situación.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

En java existen 2 tipos de rutas las Relativas y las Absolutas, en tu caso estas utilizando una ruta absoluta porque especificas su ubicación desde la raíz del sistema, algo que debes tener en cuenta es que un archivo posee las 2 rutas, la Absoluta que es la ruta especifica en tu sistema operativo y la relativa que es con relación a donde se esta ejecutando tu jar.

Lo que puedes hacer es este cambio:

```
FileWriter escritura = new FileWriter("ficheroNuevo.txt");
```

y cuando ejecutes el programa desde el jar creara el archivo en la misma carpeta donde se encuentre el jar, a esto llamaríamos una ruta relativa porque no especificas la ruta completa sino una ruta en relación a tu jar, puedes buscar mas información en Internet que hay en abundancia sobre este tema para entender mas a fondo como hacer aplicaciones mas avanzadas de estos 2 conceptos.

Comment: Buena respuesta, lo dejas muy claro. :D

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! :)